Are constant phase shifts of arbitrary signals possible?
I’m currently trying to model an interference effect occurring on an RF chip. Specifically, one signal experiences a reduction in amplitude and a phase shift due to some circuit on the chip. To model this, I’m using the following transfer function $$ H(j\omega)=\eta e^{j\lambda}$$
where $\eta$ represents the amplitude reduction factor, and $\lambda$ is the phase shift. In the frequency range of interest, I assume both amplitude and phase shift are independent of frequency.
However, when I test this model using the simplest input signal $E_{in}(t) = E_0 \sin(\omega_1 t)$, the output I get is $$E_{out}=\eta e^{j\lambda}E_0\sin(\omega_1 t).$$
This result is no longer real, as I would expect the phase shift to apply directly to the sine function, rather than resulting in a complex output. I deliberately chose not to use a complex representation for $E_{in}(t)$ because the goal is to eventually handle arbitrary real signals, not just harmonics.
My question is: Is it possible to model this kind of amplitude and phase shift for arbitrary real input signals using this formalism, or is there a better approach to handle this situation?

A transfer function $H(\mathfrak j \omega)$ means that if the input signal is $$x(t)=\Re [Ae^{\mathfrak j \omega t}]=|A|\cos(\omega t + \angle A) \tag{1},$$ where $A=|A|e^{\mathfrak j \angle A},$ then the output signal is $$y(t)=\Re [A H(\mathfrak j \omega) e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}]
\\ =|A||H|\cos(\omega t + \angle A +\angle H)\tag{2}.$$
Both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are real.
